# Trying to execute this in Athena SQL. I have '75' as default tax_type which i need to replace with '76' for 20% of tax_amt

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, divide, percentile

rying to execute this in Athena SQL. I have '75' as default tax_type which i need to replace with '76' for 20% of tax_amt

Current output as is

```
geocode  tax_type  tax_amt
32         75       10
32         75       15
32         75       20
32         75       18
32         75       20
32         75       17
```

I need output as

```
geocode  tax_type  tax_amt
32         75       10
32         75       15
32         75       20
32         75       18
32         76       20
32         75       17
```

SQL

```
SELECT CASE when d.tax_auth = '1' THEN substring(b.geocode,1,2) || '0000000' 
WHEN d.tax_auth = '2' THEN substring(b.geocode,1,5) || '0000' ELSE b.geocode END AS GEOCODE,
b.JUR_NAME as JURIS_NAME,
CAST(COUNT(a.tax_amt)/COUNT(*)*100 AS DECIMAL(30,2)) AS PERCENTILE,
CASE WHEN substring(b.geocode,1,2) = '32' AND d.tax_type = '75' 
         THEN 
              CASE 
                  WHEN CAST(COUNT(a.tax_amt)/COUNT(*)*100 AS DECIMAL(30,2)) = 0.20 
                  THEN REPLACE (d.tax_type,'75','76') 
              END
         ELSE 
              CASE 
                  WHEN CAST(COUNT(a.tax_amt)/COUNT(*)*100 AS DECIMAL(30,2)) = 0.80 
                  THEN d.tax_type 
              END 
         END AS TAX_TYPE,
CAST (d.tax_rate AS DECIMAL (30,5)) AS TAX_RATE,
SUM(CAST(a.tax_amt as DECIMAL(30,2))) AS TAX,
substring(b.geocode,1,2) AS STATE_GEO,
'PPD Boost Usage' AS ID,
d.tax_auth AS TAX_AUTH,
f.auth_name AS AUTH_NAME,
CASE WHEN substring(b.geocode,1,2) = '72' THEN '417' ELSE '317' END AS BU,
c.tax_descrp AS TAX_DESCRP,
CASE WHEN b.geocode like '%-%-%' THEN b.geocode ELSE substring(geocode,1,2) || '-' || substring(geocode,3,3) || '-' || substring(geocode,6,4) END AS GEOMASK,
'NO' AS COST_RECOVERY_IDENTIFIER,
CONCAT(substring(b.geocode,1,2),d.tax_auth,d.tax_type) as GL_CROSS_REF,
substring(load_id,1,6) AS YYYYMM,
c.gl_account AS GL_ACCOUNT,
d.tax_srv_type
FROM (select * from "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_tax_fact" where dt = (select max(dt) from "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_tax_fact")) a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT g.geocode_id, g.geocode, coalesce(sq_actual_names.actual_name, g.jurisdiction_name) as JUR_NAME
FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_geocode_dim" g `enter code here`
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT replace(geocode,'-','') as stripped_geocode, max(jurisdiction_name) as actual_name
FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_geocode_dim" 
WHERE 1=1 AND dt = (select max(dt) from "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_geocode_dim")
AND (geocode = geocode OR geocode = substring(geocode,1,2) || '-' || substring(geocode,3,3) || '-' || substring(geocode,6,4))
AND jurisdiction_name <> 'U'
GROUP BY 1) sq_actual_names
on g.geocode = sq_actual_names.stripped_geocode
WHERE 1=1 AND g.dt = (select max(dt) from "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_geocode_dim")
AND (geocode = geocode OR geocode = substring(geocode,1,2) || '-' || substring(geocode,3,3) || '-' || substring(geocode,6,4))) b
ON a.geocode_id = b.geocode_id
LEFT JOIN (select * from "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_tax_code_dim" where dt = (select max(dt) from "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_tax_code_dim")) d
ON a.tax_code_id = d.tax_code_id
LEFT JOIN "sbx_accntnganalytics"."tax_auth_name" f
ON d.tax_auth = f.tax_auth
LEFT JOIN "sbx_accntnganalytics"."tax_gl_desc" c
ON d.tax_type = c.tax_type AND substring(b.geocode,1,2) = c.state_geo
GROUP BY 1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Please simplify your question (and the sample code) to highlight the specific question you are asking, and remove the "other stuff". Also, please **provide sample input data** upon which the query is running.